# Access localhost on Mac OS X from Parallels machine

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtualization, web-development, parallels

i need to test my web site, running on a local Mac, under several browsers in Windows.

I use Windows XP, installed in Parallels Desktop.

It would be great, when i will be able to access my http://localhost:3000 from Windows, sitting in virtual environment (Parallels).

How to wire all the stuff up ?

---

**Update:**

I figured out, how to access shared web-site on the mac.

I have following settings:

Parallels Desktop -> Preferences -> Network -> Shared Network

"Parallels Shared Networking Adapter #0" i tweaked with ip=192.168.123.1

From WinXP this ip is accessible via ping.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ping imac.local

Pinging imac.local [192.168.123.1] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.123.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.123.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.123.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.123.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

When on the Mac i turn the "Shared Web" on, the address "http://imac.local/~AntonAL" will get accessible from WinXP and Mac. Note, that i have set the name of my mac to "iMac", which is equivalent to ip=192.168.123.1

But, the only problem, i can't figure out is unaccessible port 3000.

So, the address "http://imac.local:3000" is still does't work from WinXP. Actually, it is not accessible even from the Mac ... possible i'm doing something wrong.

**The question is** - which address should i use in WinXP-side, to be able to access "localhost:3000" on the Mac-side? Tried ips of "Parallels Shared Networking Adapter #0", gateway, ip of the Mac, but still no success ...

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/236695/89976

Answer (score 6):

Type 'ipconfig' on your Windows command line. You will see information similar to what I see below:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdb2:2c26:f4e4:0:a1e2:ed15:e43a:daf7
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fdb2:2c26:f4e4:0:b5d9:4d70:47a:b0b0
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a1e2:ed15:e43a:daf7%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.55.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.55.1
```

If you note, in the last line is your Default Gateway and two lines above that is IPv4 Address. Default Gateway is the virtual router between your Windows and Mac OS X. Since, Windows is using IP address of x.x.x.3 and router is using x.x.x.1, then Mac is available at x.x.x.2. In my case I am able to access Mac at 10.211.55.2. So you can access your web server using http://x.x.x.2/ and in my case I use:

```
http://10.211.55.2/
```

I have edited my Windows 'hosts' file with following entry:

```
10.211.55.2     localhost.mac
```

Now, I can type http://localhost.mac/ to access the web server running on my Mac. Though, this step of editing 'hosts' file in not required, it helps me.

As a side note, you can access your Windows based web server from Mac using the IPv4 address you get when you type 'ipconfig' on Windows.

Another way you can get Mac's virtual IP address is to type the following command on Mac OS X's Terminal:

```
ifconfig vnic0
```

'vnic0' is the virtual ethernet that Parallels installs on your Mac. In case, you have multiple Virtual Machine instances running you will see multiple virtual ethernet. All these virtual ethernets will begin with the word 'vnic'. If you have two VMs running, you will see 'vnic0' and 'vnic1' listed when you simply run 'ifconfig' command on Terminal.

In my case, when I type 'ipconfig vnic0' I get the following output, you will note that you get inet x.x.x.x IP address listed which.

```
vnic0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 00:1c:42:00:00:08 
    inet 10.211.55.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.211.55.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

I hope this helps you.

Cheers!

SG

Answer (score 5):

Try finding out your Mac's local IP address and accessing the webpage on your VM using that address.

You can find out your Mac's IP address under System Preferences, using the command ifconfig, or with some apps or Dashboard widgets (like [iSlayer's iStat](http://www.islayer.com/apps/)).

Comment: it does not works

Comment: For me, simply getting Mac's IP with ifconfig and browsing to http://ipfromifconfig:9000 worked. Remember to check that your server application doesn't have something like "restricted access only from localhost" etc

Answer (score 1):

My successful settings for access `localhost:8001` for win (`localhost` running on my Macintosh).

1. Setup Parallels Shared network: In menu settings `Configure > Hardware > Network adapter 1: Default Adapter` and then in Configure settings: `Preferences > Advanced > Network: Change Settings > Shared`.
2. Then run this in the Macintosh command line: `ifconfig | grep inet`.
3. Get the IP from subnet. Mine is `10.211.55.2`.
4. If your local site running on the Mac as: `http://localhost:8001/`  Then be sure setup hosts: Open in mac `/etc/hosts` and write it down—like in my case—`10.211.55.2 localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1 localhost`
5. Be sure thats your port is open `8001` in Windows and Mac. Follow next steps.
6. For Macintosh: `nmap -p 8001 10.211.55.2` it should success status (port open).
7. For Windows: `telnet 10.211.55.2 8001` it should success status (port open).
8. Open hosts file in Windows and write. For example: `10.211.55.2 localhost`
9. Open the Windows browser and open the site `http://localhost:8001`

Comment: in cmd.exe `telnet is not recognized as an internal or external command...`

Comment: Setting adapter1: Default Adapter was not required for me on Parallels version 10; Shared Network was sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Just run in the terminal:

```
ifconfig
```

And go to vnic0: inet address from the Parallels (like http://1x.2xx.5x.2:3000/ for ex.)