# Forward Ports on Parallels

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, port-forwarding, parallels

I have a dev server on port 8080 on my mac, and I'm trying to access it from a clean installation of Windows 7 in parallels.

Ipconfig says my VM's IP address is 10.211.55.3.  I can access the mac web sharing service at 10.211.55.2:80/ but not my own webserver (GAE) at 10.211.55.2:8080/

- Parallels set to Shared Networking and is able to browse the internet fine
- Firewall is off in both windows and mac
- I installed bonjour for windows as a few forums said to do.  I can then use my-computer-name.local/ but same deal as before, port 8080 doesn't work
- Tried adding a port forwarding entry of 8080,TCP,10.211.55.3,8080 to Parallels Desktop > Preferences > Advanced > Port forwarding rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you access your testing server on :8080 from other real machines on your network? It could be that your development server software accepts only connections from your local machine (127.0.0.1 aka `localhost`).

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  For appengine I needed to use the flag --address=0.0.0.0 for it to accept connections from any IP.

Answer (score 1):

Jake's answer worked for me, too. On jboss, just start the server with

```
-b 0.0.0.0
```

and access it via

```
http://COMPUTERNAME:8080
```

Note: no need to use "local"

Related: [Access localhost on Mac OS X from Parallels machine](https://superuser.com/q/153624/89976)